# configuration error. I hosted a site through WebsitePanel . The site has targetFramework 4.0. The following error showed

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework-version, target-framework

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: C:\HostingSpaces\wfirc.org\wfirc.org\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 9

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8669; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you have an attribute of targetFramework="4.0" in the web.config but the App Pool is set to run ASP.NET 2.0. The targetFramework attribute is entirely unrecognized by ASP.NET 2.0 - so changing it to 2.0 won't have the desired effect.

Contact Support / Your Administrator and have the AppPool switched to 4.0.

You could also remove the attribute entirely, however, if your site was coded with the 4.0 Framework, then I'm sure something else will cause an error as well.